# Why the sizeof() is not giving the different result for int array?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I am using codeblock in Windows 10 for C programs. I was writing this below program but instead of giving 12 it gives 24 as output. I have also checked it using online compiler but still it giving the same output.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int num[]={5,7,9,0,1,7};
  printf("%d",sizeof(num));
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Don't use `"%d"` to print `sizeof` use `"%zu"`. Also, why should it be 12? Didn't you think of printing `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @Rock You didn't explained why did you expected the Output to be 12. Please Explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but instead of giving 12 it gives 24 as output

Not sure why you would expect the output to be `12`. You are probably assuming `sizeof(int)` to be `2` which is not necessarily true on all platforms.

`sizeof(int)` is platform dependent and `sizeof(int)` is `4` on your platform. Hence, the output is `24`.

Note: To print a `size_t` (which is what `sizeof()` returns), use `%zu`:

```
  printf("%zu",sizeof(num));
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps your understanding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num[] = { 5, 7, 9, 0, 1, 7 };

    printf("sizeof(int) = %zu\n", sizeof(int));

    printf("sizeof(num[0]) = %zu\n", sizeof(num[0]));

    printf("sizeof(num) = %zu\n", sizeof(num));

    printf("number of elements in num[]: %zu\n", sizeof(num) / sizeof(num[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(num[0]) = 4
sizeof(num) = 24
number of elements in num[]: 6
```

Now if you translate this into Pascal:

```
program sizetest;

var
  num: array[1..6] of integer;

begin
  writeln('sizeof(integer) = ', sizeof(integer));
  writeln('sizeof(num[1]) = ', sizeof(num[1]));
  writeln('sizeof(num) = ', sizeof(num));
  writeln('number of elements in num[]: ', sizeof(num) / sizeof(num[1]));
end.
```

You get the following output:

```
sizeof(integer) = 2
sizeof(num[1]) = 2
sizeof(num) = 12
number of elements in num[]: 6
```

And finally (and I hope it won't destroy your world) look at python which supports very large integers:

```
import sys

sys.getsizeof(int())
24
```

Yes, twentyfour! So now it should be clear that the size of int really depends on the platform.

Also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Comment: I expected 12 because the size of int is 2 byte. I know that this is platform dependent. But the online copiler is also giving the same

Comment: So if you know it is platform dependent, why do you think it's 2??

Comment: Because in every book its written that its size is 2. So I thought that online compilers will be of that form. Actually this question was asked in a aptitude test. So, what should I choose as the answer?

Comment: What was the exact question in this aptitude test??

Comment: what will be the output of                                               #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int num[]={5,7,9,0,1,7};
  printf("%d",sizeof(num));
  return 0;
 }                                                                                                                                                                 a) 12  b)garbage value  c)error  d)no output